# Is there a way to make media queries select a specific page?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I made a site using separate CSS files and now I want to combine them. The problem is that I can't simply copy/paste everything into 1 file because my media queries have different values for html, h1, h2, h3.

Is there a way to make media queries specify a page so that it only selects the html and h1 of the home page, without changing the html and h1 of the contact page?

Edit: this is for a Wordpress custom template, so all pages will share the same header and html opening tag.

Example:

How would I combine these two files?

index.css:

```
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) {
    html {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

contact.css:

```
html {
    font-size: 18px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) {
    html {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to be more specific with your styles... Use CSS classes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors (or ids) instead of the generic `html`and `h1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a class to that *specific page* like this:

```
<html class="specific-page">
```

And in the CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) {
    html.specific-page {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    .specific-page h1 {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Or:

1. Add this `<link />` to that specific page alone.
2. Or as a `<style>` tag in that specific page.

Comment: Thanks! But I forgot to mention something: I'm creating a Wordpress custom template, so all pages will share the same header and <html>. Is there another way I can do it without selecting the html tag?

Comment: @Calisto You can give page level styles in WordPress. `:)` Else, for the specific page, just give: `document.body.parentNode.classList.add("specific-page");` LoL. `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the body class if it is not already used in your theme:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

This will automatically add specific classes for the home page, posts, archives etc. You can then have a set of CSS rules that is used globally, and after that, you can define all the specific styles of the other pages.

```
body {
    font-size: 16px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

body.class-name {
    font-size: 18px;
}
h1.class-name {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 700px) {
    body {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }

    html.class-name {
        font-size: 19px;
    }
    h1.class-name {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
    }
}
```

Comment: `body !== html`

Comment: I know, but this is best practice in WordPress.
https://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/#article-header-id-1

Comment: Already, WordPress uses bad practises by using `!important` and mixing OO and non OO PHP components. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Most WordPress pages have a class like -> .page-id-12345  - where 12345 is unique to that page and does not change.  Pages not containing this very distinctive class but will (or should) have a class defined that does uniquely identify it e.g.  Geodirectory search results page has a top level class named ".search-results".